# Why does ChatGPT always reply with a conversation to the word "example"?

Tags: chatgpt, gpt

When asking ChatGPT,

> Example

It usually replies with a conversation between two people.

Examples:

- Beach Trip Planning

> Person A: Hi there! How was your weekend?
>
> Person B: Hello! My weekend was fantastic, thank you for asking. I
> went hiking with some friends and enjoyed the beautiful weather. How
> about you?
>
> Person A: That sounds wonderful! I had a relaxing weekend at home. I
> watched some movies and caught up on my reading. By the way, have you
> tried the new café that opened downtown?
>
> Person B: Oh, yes! I actually went there yesterday. The coffee was
> excellent, and they had a great selection of pastries too. I think
> it's going to become my new favorite spot.
>
> Person A: I'm glad you liked it! I'll definitely check it out soon. By
> the way, do you have any plans for the upcoming holidays?
>
> Person B: Not yet, but I'm thinking of taking a short trip to the
> beach. It would be nice to unwind and have some fun in the sun.
>
> Person A: That sounds like a fantastic idea! I hope you have a
> fantastic time. Let me know if you need any recommendations or tips
> for your beach trip.
>
> Person B: Thanks, I appreciate that! I'll definitely keep that in
> mind. So, what about you? Any exciting plans for the holidays?
>
> Person A: I haven't decided yet, but I might visit my family in
> another city. It's been a while since I saw them, and it would be
> lovely to spend some quality time together.
>
> Person B: That sounds like a heartwarming plan. I'm sure your family
> will be delighted to see you. Whatever you end up doing, I hope you
> have a fantastic time!
>
> Person A: Thank you! Likewise, I hope you have a wonderful time at the
> beach. Let's catch up again soon and share our holiday experiences.
>
> Person B: Absolutely! Looking forward to it. Have a great day!
>
> Person A: You too! Take care. Goodbye for now!

- Plant Processes Explained

> User: Hi there! Can you tell me a joke?
>
> ChatGPT: Of course! Why don't scientists trust atoms? Because they
> make up everything!
>
> User: Haha, that's a good one! By the way, can you explain how
> photosynthesis works?
>
> ChatGPT: Certainly! Photosynthesis is the process by which plants
> convert light energy from the sun into chemical energy in the form of
> glucose. It takes place in the chloroplasts of plant cells. During
> photosynthesis, plants absorb carbon dioxide (CO2) from the atmosphere
> through tiny pores called stomata and water from the roots. With the
> help of sunlight, the chlorophyll in the chloroplasts captures the
> energy and initiates a series of chemical reactions. These reactions
> combine carbon dioxide and water to produce glucose (C6H12O6) and
> oxygen (O2) as byproducts. The glucose serves as food for the plant,
> while oxygen is released into the atmosphere as a waste product.
>
> User: Thanks for the explanation! I've always been curious about that.
> What other processes are vital for a plant's survival?
>
> ChatGPT: Besides photosynthesis, there are several other essential
> processes for a plant's survival. One of them is cellular respiration.
> Cellular respiration is the process by which plants (and other
> organisms) break down glucose and other organic molecules to release
> energy. In this process, oxygen is consumed, and carbon dioxide and
> water are produced as byproducts, essentially the reverse of
> photosynthesis.
>
> Another important process is transpiration, which is the loss of water
> vapor from the plant's leaves and stems. It helps in nutrient uptake
> from the roots and also plays a role in regulating temperature and
> maintaining plant structure.
>
> Additionally, plants rely on pollination for reproduction. Pollination
> is the transfer of pollen from the male reproductive organs (anthers)
> to the female reproductive organs (stigma) of flowers. This process is
> crucial for the formation of seeds and fruits.
>
> User: I never realized how many processes are involved in a plant's
> life! Thanks for enlightening me.
>
> ChatGPT: You're welcome! Nature is fascinating, and plants have
> evolved amazing mechanisms to survive and thrive. If you have any more
> questions or need further explanations, feel free to ask!

Comment: I think ChatGPT is just giving you an example of whatever you've talked about previously.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I don' think so. I created a brand new prompt (targeting gpt 3.5) and typed just "example". Four of the five times, ChatGPT responded with an example conversation about a seemingly random topic. It would have had no context regarding any previous conversation to base that off of, and even if it did, I rarely ask for both sides of a conversation from chatGPT.

Comment: your title doesn't seem consistent with post body. Are you saying the just typing in "example" into chatgpt input box gives a long conversation as a result, or typing in the phrases in your question body result in the conversations?

Comment: @user13267 Feel free to edit the post - I mean typing in "example" into ChatGPT input box gives a long conversation as a result.

Comment: I already did, i edited your title. Other than that, as  this is not a trivial edit ( not simple grammar or spelling errors) and about making the question more understandable, you should be editing it yourself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this question can be directly answered without knowing the closed source of how ChatGPT operates.

ChatGPT will always attempt to provide you with *something*, instead of just stating "I don't know what you mean" or asking for more information. I imagine there is also a lot of written dialog in ChatGPT's training data. Between the training data, the weighting towards "helpful" responses, and the inferred context of "example", a conversation between two people seems reasonable.

Have you asked ChatGPT to explain itself?

> When my previous prompt was just "example", without anything more, why did you select a conversation as the example instead of another kind or style of response? I don't want to provide an alternate "example", just explain why you chose a conversation.

> *My apologies for any confusion. The reason I provided an example conversation is that as an AI language model, my primary function is to engage in natural language conversations and provide helpful responses. Since the prompt "example" doesn't specify a particular type of response, I defaulted to offering an example conversation to demonstrate how the AI can interact with users in a conversational manner.*

Comment: Note that ChatGPT's explanations of ChatGPT aren't likely to be correct. [It has no reflective ability.](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/147/10)

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely because the model is primed with a pre-prompt to make it respond like a helpful assistant. I imagine it might look something like:

“You are an assistant striving to give helpful and accurate responses in a conversational format.”

If it sees the prompt “example” after this, it thinks you want an example of a conversation between the user and assistant.